# Flutter New Project Error const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

Tags: flutter

Flutter new project showing error with key, when I click run button it showing these error,

- lib/main.dart:7:20: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
- 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart' ('../../android/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/key.dart').
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  ^^^
  Failed to compile application.

Note: I'm using all updated latest version tools.

My Code is bellow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        child: Text("Hello World"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can delete this line `const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);`

Comment: Also take a look at this tutorial to better understand what a minimal app code should look like (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab). Right now your app doesn't have a Scaffold so after you fix issue with a key you will face all other problems with layout and rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is about null-safety feature of dart.
When you use named parameters, you need to provide default non-null value or use nullable value. For example

`const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`
or
`const MyApp({Key key = const GlobalKey()}) : super(key: key);`

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning rules in your analysis_options.yaml:

```
linter:
  rules:
    prefer_const_constructors : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove (const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key) ) part .It is work for me

Comment: it was a bug, they did not add " ? " between MyApp({Key key}) but in a later version they added MyApp({Key? key}), so now it works without error.

Comment: yes, I work with the previous version. thanks for mentioning that!